# API3 Error Custom Fields

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields, api, groups

Deleted Custom Field set called Area and added a new custom field set called Regions and I get the below. I cannot access any Contacts now.

```
CiviCRM_API3_Exception: "'group_areas' is not a valid option for field custom_group_id"

CiviCRM_API3_Exception: "'group_areas' is not a valid option for field custom_group_id"

#0 /home/xxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/org.civicoop.areas/CRM/Areas/Config.php(17): civicrm_api3("CustomField", "getsingle", (Array:3))
#1 /home/xxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/org.civicoop.areas/CRM/Areas/Config.php(28): CRM_Areas_Config->__construct()
#2 /home/xxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/org.civicoop.areas/areas.php(75): CRM_Areas_Config::singleton()
#3 /home/xxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Hook.php(283): areas_civicrm_fieldOptions("Contact", "custom_35", (Array:0), (Array:1))
#4 /home/xxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Hook/WordPress.php(136): CRM_Utils_Hook->runHooks((Array:29), "civicrm_fieldOptions", 4, "Contact", "custom_35", (Array:0), (Array:1), NULL, NULL)
#5 /home/xxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Core/CiviEventDispatcher.php(249): CRM_Utils_Hook_WordPress->invokeViaUF(4, "Contact", "custom_35", (Array:0), (Array:1), NULL, NULL, "civicrm_fieldOptions")
#6 /home/xxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php(214): Civi\Core\CiviEventDispatcher::delegateToUF(Object(Civi\Core\Event\GenericHookEvent), "hook_civicrm_fieldOptions", Object(Civi\Core\CiviEventDispatcher))
#7 /home/xxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php(44): Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->doDispatch((Array:1), "hook_civicrm_fieldOptions", Object(Civi\Core\Event\GenericHookEvent))
#8 /home/xxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Core/CiviEventDispatcher.php(198): Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->dispatch("hook_civicrm_fieldOptions", Object(Civi\Core\Event\GenericHookEvent))
#9 /home/xxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Hook.php(167): Civi\Core\CiviEventDispatcher->dispatch("hook_civicrm_fieldOptions", Object(Civi\Core\Event\GenericHookEvent))
#10 /home/xxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Hook.php(1002): CRM_Utils_Hook->invoke((Array:4), "Contact", "custom_35", (Array:0), (Array:1), NULL, NULL, "civicrm_fieldOptions")
#11 /home/xxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/BAO/CustomField.php(320): CRM_Utils_Hook::fieldOptions("Contact", "custom_35", (Array:0), (Array:1))
#12 /home/xxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/BAO/CustomField.php(1109): CRM_Core_BAO_CustomField->getOptions()
#13 /home/xxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/BAO/CustomGroup.php(1930): CRM_Core_BAO_CustomField::displayValue("4", Object(CRM_Core_BAO_CustomField), 1805)
#14 /home/xxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contact/Page/View/Summary.php(56): CRM_Core_BAO_CustomGroup::buildCustomDataView(Object(CRM_Contact_Page_View_Summary), (Array:4), FALSE, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1805, 1)
#15 /home/xxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contact/Page/View/Summary.php(77): CRM_Contact_Page_View_Summary->preProcess()
#16 /home/xxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(319): CRM_Contact_Page_View_Summary->run((Array:3), NULL)
#17 /home/xxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(69): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:14))
#18 /home/xxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(36): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:3))
#19 /home/xxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php(1199): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3))
#20 /home/xxxxxxx/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(307): CiviCRM_For_WordPress->invoke("")
#21 /home/xxxxxxx/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(331): WP_Hook->apply_filters("", (Array:1))
#22 /home/xxxxxxx/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(474): WP_Hook->do_action((Array:1))
#23 /home/xxxxxxx/public_html/wp-admin/admin.php(259): do_action("toplevel_page_CiviCRM")
#24 {main}
```

NOTE: I disabled the Areas extension and it appears to have fixed things. I am leaving this open as I would like to find out what I am doing wrong or if it might be a code issue.

Comment: There's an argument that the extension could mark the custom group reserved or prevent someone deleting it if it's required for the extension to function. If you uninstall and re-install the extension I expect now it would recreate the fields.

Comment: @Demerit I believe your answer is the best that will come and completely solved my issue as I had Disabled and not Uninstalled. It fixed the issues I had and I simply added a custom field set to an existing area where it best applied. There is no Accept Answer yet and I will check it for this when it appears. Thanks again!

Comment: Ok thanks - I have copied into the answer box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an argument that the extension could mark the custom group reserved or prevent someone deleting it if it's required for the extension to function. If you uninstall and re-install the extension I expect now it would recreate the fields.